# Angular Redirect on HTTP 401

Tags: angular, typescript

I wrote the following code:

**AuthenticationService**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  public currentUser: string

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    ) { }

  login(username:string, password:string){
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/api/token/', {username: username, password: password})
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access)
          localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh)
        })
      )
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token')
  }

  getJWToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token')
  }

  getRefreshToken(){
    return localStorage.getItem('refresh_token')
  }

  refreshToken(){
    let refreshToken : string = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token'); 

    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8000/api/token/refresh/', {"refresh": refreshToken}).pipe(
      map(data => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access)
      },
        error => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      )
    )
  }
}
```

**TokenInterceptor**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, first, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../services/authentication.service'

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public authService : AuthenticationService ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {    
      return next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
      .pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return this.refreshToken()
          .pipe(switchMap(
            data => next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
          ))
        } else {
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }));
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
    return request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    });
  } 

  private refreshToken(){
    return this.authService.refreshToken()
  }
}
```

I want to redirect to the login page upon having a 401 error in the refreshToken method of the AuthenticationService but I don't seem to be able to catch the error with the 'error' part of the 'map' function in this method. How to proceed on this?

Comment: Why do you think the second argument to map would be a function to handle the error? That's not what e.g. https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map suggests. Why not use the same method to catch an error that you did in intercept, i.e. catchError?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this code ever executed?

```
        this.refreshToken()
          .pipe(switchMap(
            data => next.handle(this.addToken(request, 
                  localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
        ))
```

I think this is missing after pipe:

```
   .subscribe( o => {});
```

Without subscribe an observable is not fired.

The catchError in the pipe is to change the object when an error occurs.
To listen to an exception you should set an exception handler as second argument of subscribe():

```
    this.refreshToken()
      .pipe(switchMap(
        data => next.handle(this.addToken(request, localStorage.getItem('access_token')))
      ))
      .subscribe( 
          o => { console.info(o); },
          err => { console.err(err); }
      );
```

An TokenInterceptor is a good place to add a token to every outgoning request.

But a better place for checks (with an redirect) is an CanActivate guard:

Pseudo code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardCanActivate implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

    constructor(
        private readonly router: Router,
        private readonly authService: authService
    ) {
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.canActivateChild(route, state);
    }

    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.checkLogin(state.url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) return true;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

See: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate